# Javascript flot not showing data series

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm using [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) to display some data on a bar graph. But my data isn't displaying for some reason, and I have no idea why.

My data series is correct as far as I can see, but it still won't show.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9jhpyne4/1/

Code:

```
var plotData = [
    [1, 12.35],
    [2, 34.6],
    [3, 56.7],
    [4, 4.35]
]; 

$.plot($("#main-chart"), plotData, {
bars: {
    show: true,
    lineWidth: 0,
    fill: true,
    fillColor: {
        colors: [{
            opacity: 0.8
        }, {
            opacity: 0.1
        }]
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data which you pass to plot function needs to have some metadata (like label and color):

```
var data = [
    [1, 12.35],
    [2, 34.6],
    [3, 56.7],
    [4, 4.35]
];
var dataset = [{ label: "a label", data: data, color: "red" }];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jhpyne4/3/

Comment: You don't really need the object with the metadata. The only mandatory thing is the additional array around the `data` array. (All in all the data needs three stages of arrays: data point, data series and data overall, the last one was missing here.)

Answer (score 1):

The console throw an error regarding your #main-chart width & height as invalid.

Changing your width & height from percentage to pixel based seems to fixed the error.

## HTML

```
<div id="main-chart" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
```

Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jhpyne4/1/)

Comment: Looks like the graph frame is displaying now, but I don't see any of the data points in your JSFiddle.

Comment: as @MaximillianLaumeister pointed out, it is now displaying the graph, but not the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the width and height.

```
<div id="main-chart" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></div>
```

And You need to change a little your plotData variable to:

```
var plotData = [
[[1,0], [1, 12.35]],
[[2,0], [2, 34.6]],
[[3,0], [3, 56.7]],
[[4,0], [4, 4.35]]];
```

You can see a complete example here: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardofranca/myxx8evs/)

Comment: This has already been answered. Also your example works, but isn't the correct way of doing it according to the docs